# [TestNG]Couldn't find the testng.xml in the jar file,running all the classes [TestNG] [ERROR] Cannot instantiate class StepDefinition.FreeSPHomeSteps

Tags: pom.xml, cucumber-jvm, aws-device-farm, appium-android

I'm trying to execute my scripts in AWS Device farm. But I'm getting the above parsing error.

Also: "Tests skipped due to test package parsing error. Please check Parsing result for more details." is being displayed in AWS console.

Project details: Java-TestNG-Cucumber combo

Project structure: [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j00f9.png)

## Also below provided my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>TestSuite</groupId>
<artifactId>AndroidBusinessApp</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<!-- <groupId>TestSuite</groupId> <artifactId>AndroidBusinessApp</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <packaging>jar</packaging> -->

<name>AndroidBusinessApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- <id>TestSuite</id> -->
<build>

    <plugins>
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.20</version> </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <!-- Adding maven comiler plugin and surefire plugin in Build is manadatory -->
        <!--****The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of your project**** -->
        <!-- Enable the forkcount only if you want to run parallel , will trigger 
            #n no of JVM -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-testclasses</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/upload/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>
                                    ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}
                                </directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>Testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <includes>
                <include>**/AppiumServerTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>


<dependencies>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ********* https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting 
        ******** -->
    <!-- ********* http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccucumber-extentsreport 
        ************** -->
    <!-- 1st is for Cucumber Extent advance Reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add a dependency for the Appium test extensions to execute in Mobile 
        center -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.microsoft.appcenter</groupId> <artifactId>appium-test-extension</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0</version> </dependency> -->

</dependencies>
```

Thanks in advanace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the testng.xml work in device farm it will need to be added to the root of the jar in the zip-with-dependencies.zip

Here is a pull request showing how to do that 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/pull/14

I am not sure about cucumber tho.  I have not tried it but it may not be supported in DFarm currently.

HTH
  James

Comment: Thank you james. I've tried but still the same error is displayed for me. Anything else that I miss in my code. Can you please advise on this issue.

Comment: It worked James. Thank you! I've added my testng.xml in a different location. Now added inside src/main/resources and it worked :-)